# What's the status of AI beings in the Star Wars universe: people or property?

Tags: star-wars

AI technology is obviously pretty advanced in the Star Wars universe. This question explains why AI droids aren't more commonly used in perilous situations:
[Why Did the Empire Use Storm/Clone Troopers and not Droids?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7753/why-did-the-empire-use-storm-clone-troopers-and-not-droids) 
(TL/DR - their AI was crippled to make them more obedient).

However, the films (the only canon reference I'm familiar with) features a number of droids which have apparently human-level intellect and are capable of functioning entirely independently. C3P0 is the obvious example. IG-88 is another (whose existence, I might add, undermines the idea that battle droids are always stupid).

At no point in is there any sign that these robots are particularly special or rare. They are not treated as valuable objects, and the organic characters in the films don't react to them with any surprise. So it follows that they must be reasonably easy to produce.

The way they are treated seems to fall into an uncomfortable gray area between objects and sentient beings. My question is whether there's any canon references as to the status of AI entities in Star Wars as "people"?

Comment: Agree that this is a duplicate, although the title does not make the inference obvious (else I would have found it researching!). Thanks.

Comment: I like your question much better. It makes the search topically for the status of droids easier to find. One day we will address whether questions should be clarified for easier searching...